# Create a classic single variate R ts object (not xts object) from a csv file

Tags: r

I have a `csv` file `y.csv` which is structured as below:

```
Date,   PX_LAST
1/30/1987,  5.03
2/27/1987,  4.82
3/31/1987,  4.46
4/30/1987,  4.55
...
```

I want to read this `csv` file into a classic R `ts` object (nb **not** an `xts` object) with dates; the package that I want to use requires a classic `ts` object. I have tried the following (which is taken from one of the many other questions on timeseries in R):

```
w_zoo <- read.zoo(file="y.csv", sep=",", header = TRUE, index = 1:1, tz = "", format = "%m/%d/%Y")
w_xts <- as.xts(w_zoo)
w_ts <- as.ts(w_xts)
```

but cannot seem to get the dates into the timeseries. In this case `dput(w_ts)`  gives

```
structure(c(5.03, 4.82, 4.46, 4.55, 4.24, 4.29, 4.03, 3.79, 4.02), ...
.Tsp = c(1, 1339201, 0.000277777777777778), class = "ts")
```

How do I achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some painful searching on the internet, I understood how to do this:

First read the data into a dataframe:

```
df <- read.csv('y.csv', header=TRUE);
```

and then create the timeseries, piece-by-piece;

```
w_ts <- ts(df$PX_LAST, start = c(as.numeric(format(as.Date(df[1:1, c('Date')], format= "%m/%d/%Y"), "%Y")), as.numeric(format(as.Date(df[1:1, c('Date')], format= "%m/%d/%Y"), "%m"))), frequency=12).
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to coerce a `Date` class into a `ts` object. As stated in the help file for `ts`, the object is meant to "represent data which has been sampled at equispaced points in time". Its associated `tsp` attribute is a simple way to keep track of start, end, and sampling frequency without the need for a vector of specific dates.

In a case like this where the data were sampled at roughly monthly intervals, the `ts` object is going to have a long string of `NA`'s in between observations. I don't know what method you want to use for the `ts` object, but perhaps you could aggregate the data into a more coarse temporal resolution (e.g., month) and use that as a time index instead?

Comment: Thanks. The data is monthly and I don't have a strong opinion on how the date is formatted; my interest in going from a csv file to a ts object that describes accurately the data. Thanks.